# Every time I create a simple nav bar at the top of my page, the bar is too far right

Tags: html, css

Here is my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcFflA4fsTU&feature=youtu.be. I put the nav bar at the top using position: absolute, top: 0px, and left: 0px, and width: 100%. I have no idea why this is happening. Thanks for all the help.

```css
nav {
 background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 100%;
 font-size: 20px;
 font-family: Arial;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px;
}

nav a {
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%); 
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 21px;
}

nav a:hover {
 background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 90%);
 color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <a href="">BUTTON</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: There needs to be no padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `nav`'s width as `100%`, and you additionally add `40px` of total horizontal padding to the element (`20px` left, `20px` right).

The following line ensures that `width: 100%` (and `height: 100%`) doesn't extend beyond `100%` if you add `padding: 20px` to an element.

```css
* { 
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Without `border-box`, your `nav` is wider than `100%`—it's `100%` + `40px`, which causes the horizontal scrollbar.

With `border-box`, your `nav` is `100%` *in total*, with the padding still applied.

Read more about the box model [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

You're possibly also seeing the browser's default user-agent styles. Add the following to remove the default margin:

```css
body { 
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: So, I'm kind of new to the scene of CSS. Do you mind explaining what either of those do? Also, I have heard about *, but I just looked it up, and I read it was for IE browsers? Thanks for all the help anyway, because this did fix it.

Comment: @ryanh The `*` means "all elements".

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, this all actually makes sense now.

Comment: @ryanh I cleaned up my answer so it's more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

i think it because of combination width 100% and padding: 20px;

```
nav {
    background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 10%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Ok that actually makes sense. You and @Andy Hoffman both helped. I just looked it up in w3schools and I see now that when adding padding to an element, it adds to the width of an element unless specifying a box-sizing attribute (unless I'm wrong here). And for something like a nav bar, you don't need padding on the right or left. Thank you so much.